# TFS reporting for continuous integration builds

Tags: visual-studio-2012, continuous-integration, integration-testing, tfsbuild

We use TFS 2012 for our build management, source control etc. Our development environment is VS 2012.
We run nightly builds which run unit/integration and automation(web driver) tests to test different aspects of our systems.

We would like to have easy visibility of the results.

1. See graphically for any build definition the results of the test runs(how many passed/failed).
2. See graphically historical information so you can compare and see when tests started breaking etc.
3. Be able to drill into any one "instance" of a build definition to see information on the tests that failed.. name of tests that failed, why they failed etc..

Is there any out of the box tool that provides this information with TFS, or do we have to write our own tool?

Answer (score 0):

It's a shame you're not yet on TFS 2013 as Microsoft and SonarQube recently teamed up to deliver better integration between TFS and Sonar, [providing a much richer reporting and comparison platform](http://www.sonarqube.org/announcing-sonarqube-integration-with-msbuild-and-team-build/). This currently targets only TFS 2013 and newer though. The ALM Rangers provided a [thorough installation guide](http://aka.ms/vsartdsq). The integration was announced at //Build last week and there is an [extensive walkthrough available through from one of the conference talks](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-696).

Back in the standard TFS world the exact report you're asking for doesn't really exist. There are a number of reports that fill in certain of your requests and the warehouse will allow you to create the report you want, but that will take quite some effort. The standard reports can pose as a guide though, as many of the problems you're trying to solve have already been solved by Microsoft.

- [Build Quality Indicators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd380683(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Build Success over Time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd380643(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Build Summary Report](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd380708(v=vs.110).aspx)

These reports from the standard process templates can help you (depending on the process template you have installed you may have all or some of them, in most cases you can use the build reports from any process template in any other, it's just a matter of installing them on the report server).

Guidance to [create your own custom reports can be found here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244712.aspx). And the [ALM Rangers provided a nice guide to help you along with the things you need to know when creating new reports for the datawarehouse](https://vsarreportguide.codeplex.com/).

In Web Access you can also [pin a build to the project home page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj920199.aspx), which provides a nice timeline of that specific build and you can immediately click through to the details page for that build. You can pin multiple builds to create your own dashboard.

[image]